# How many different ways to select students for a team?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> The starting line up for a basketball team of 5 players is to be selected from the team of 15 seniors and 10 juniors. The team is is set to pick a PG, SG, SF, PF, and C. How many ways are there to select the team if the PG has to be a senior and the SG has to be a junior?

So this is what I did.

1. PG - Senior
2. SG - Junior
3. SF - 14 Seniors or 9 Juniors
4. PF-  13 Seniors or 8 Juniors
5. C -  12 Seniors or 7 Juniors

so $$14(13)(12)(9)(8)(7)= 1,100,736$$ possible ways to select the team

is this right?

Comment: It doesn't look like you quite got it.  If the PG is a senior there are 15 options, and 10 options for the SG.  Note that this leaves $9+14 = 23$ team members to fill in the other positions.

Comment: So instead of looking at who is a senior and who is a junior, would you just do 23.22.21 =10,626 possible ways to select the team?

Comment: No, you have to take into account the first two positions.  Your comment shows the number of ways to fill the other three slots.

Answer (score 1):

First select the senior for the PG - 15 ways, then junior for the SG - 10 ways. 
and then you have $23\cdot22\cdot21$ ways to fill in the other positions.

In total this gives you:

$23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot15\cdot10 = 1593900$ ways to select the team